# Adding many keys to a dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

What is an efficient way of doing it ?

I may have thousands of key:value pairs(which I am extracting from jsons) to add to an existing dict. 
Should I just loop through them, or is there a mass update option ?

Comment: In what format do you have those key-value pairs? How large is the existing dict?

Comment: It's from json. The existing dict could be very small, or very large, depending on the stage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the update functions for add all of the value from another dict
`your_dict.update(all_value_to_add)`

Else you effectly can loop trough them